# Working with credential provider using vc++

Tags: visual-c++, credential-providers

I am developing custom credential provider windows login. I am using webcam for Face Recognition and I want to display preview of webcam in TILEIMAGE of window login screen.

I got a frame from webcam using callback function but I'm not able to display each frame in TILEIMAGE. Image is only changed when the user clicks on any component.

```
{   
void CSampleCredential::OnFrameRecieve(BYTE * pBuffer, long BufferSize)
{
    HWND hwndOwner = NULL;

    HDC hMem = CreateCompatibleDC ( GetDC ( NULL ) ) ;
    HBITMAP bbmp=CreateBitmapFromPixels(hMem,320,240,24,pBuffer);

    BufferSize=BufferSize;

    if (_pCredProvCredentialEvents)
    {
        _pCredProvCredentialEvents->OnCreatingWindow(&hwndOwner);

        HRESULT res =_pCredProvCredentialEvents->SetFieldBitmap(this,SFI_TILEIMAGE,bbmp);

        BufferSize=BufferSize;
        res=res;

        ::MessageBox(hwndOwner, L"OnFrameRecieve", L"True", 0);
    }
}
    }
```

How could I update the TILEIMAGE in realtime?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I solved my problem from your question. I appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show continuously any update in your GUI, you can force the Provider to enumerate your credential again by using

- [CredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb776006(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [CredentialProviderCredential::Advise()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776019(v=vs.85).aspx)

A good starting point would be the V1 [samplehardwareeventcredentialprovider](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/security/credentialproviders/samplehardwareeventcredentialprovider)